# how to get max available memory size for bitmap

Tags: android

I want to detect max available heap size before processing bitmap.
`Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` gives me 67108864.
When i process bitmap (size 20 mb ) i get an error `E/dalvikvm-heap(25396): Out of memory on a 19660816-byte allocation`.
My minimum sdk is 9, target sdk is 18. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: At best, `maxMemory()` will report the maximum possible heap size. That says nothing about whether you can allocate this bitmap. Moreover, you need a *contiguous block* of 19,660,816 bytes. I know of nothing in the Android SDK that can tell you if there is such a block, other than by trying your bitmap work and failing with the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: how can i get max available space for my bitmap? So i comress my bitmap to this space.

Comment: Try to use `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`. I think that would be helpful.

Comment: @srain: First, `freeMemory()` does not take into account possible expansions of the heap. Second, `freeMemory()` does not report the biggest possible allocated block, and so it might say that there is plenty of space, but it turns out that there is no single block that meets the need.

Comment: @user3082303: "how can i get max available space for my bitmap?" -- you don't, other than by trying to load the bitmap and handling the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Have you found a good solution to your problem?